# Does lowest edge weight algorithm works for non-complete graphs? (TSP)

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-optimization, hamiltonian-path

I am not sure if I translated this algorithm's name but it is one of ways to solve TSP.

Algorithm does these steps:

- it sorts edges by weights,
- it chooses the lowest weight edge such that it will not create a cycle and it will not create a vertice with 3 edges,
- repeat,
- in last step close the cycle

[image]

Many algorithms are guaranteed to work even in non-complete graphs and I am wondering what about this one?

Can anyone provide an explanation?

Comment: Think about this: add the missing edges, but make their weights huge.  Is there a difference to the way the algorithm operates?  Will it ever select one of the large weights if the graph is connected?  Can the last step be forced to take a huge edge?

Comment: This is a greedy heuristic for TSP but is not guaranteed to find an optimal or even a feasible tour.

Comment: I am not asking about optimal path. I am just asking if this algorithm is able to find ANY hamiltonian cycle in non-complete graph

Comment: No, it cannot. Checking if a non-complete graph has a Hamiltonian cycle is NP-complete, so it is impossible that a greedy heuristic like this one can actually solve it (by always finding a Hamiltonian cycle if there exists one).